# Android Studio class not found on path DexPathList with hyperledger fabric

Tags: java, android-studio, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

On the [Commercial paper tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/commercial_paper.html) there is an application on java, it works well. Now, I try to implement with Android Studio as a tuto.

I modified some lines to launch on an emulator and followed the pom.xml as possible to get the dependencies. But an error occurred with **org.hyperledger.fabric**, when I use **Issue.java** or **AddToWallet.java** class (Complete error at the end, for Issue app) :

**Issue** invoke `Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder();` pass by **GatewayImpl.java** and **DefaultCommitHandlers.java:70**

On class **DefaultCommitHandlers** there are **Peer**, where error start :

- `import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Peer`;
- `private static final EnumSet<Peer.PeerRole> EVENT_SOURCE_ROLES = EnumSet.of(Peer.PeerRole.EVENT_SOURCE);`

What does it mean? How can I correct this?

Complete error:

````
    Process: iti.pap.ch.pap_test, PID: 9364
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/Peer$PeerRole;
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.DefaultCommitHandlers.<clinit>(DefaultCommitHandlers.java:70)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.GatewayImpl$Builder.<init>(GatewayImpl.java:67)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.Gateway.createBuilder(Gateway.java:87)
        at iti.pap.ch.pap_test.Issue.main(Issue.java:41)
        at iti.pap.ch.pap_test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Peer$PeerRole" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/iti.pap.ch.pap_test-CLJRfC7j75Bhy3VebuP5kg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/iti.pap.ch.pap_test-CLJRfC7j75Bhy3VebuP5kg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dependency should provide it:

```
implementation "org.hyperledger.fabric:fabric-gateway-java:2.1.0"
```

And if the class is not known at runtime, disable obfuscation - or write a proper configuration for it.

Comment: Because of Duplicate class of inside `org.hyperledger.fabric-sdk-java:fabric-sdk-java` and `org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-protos`, I excluded the wrong group (**fabric-sdk-java**). Just need to invert. You showed me the right direction.